# Can we use Gravitation Force for Generation of Free electricity?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How we can generate free electricity constantly?
with the help of magnetic field we can generate free electricity but its amount is very less, also with the help of eccentric load we can generate free electricity but its speed is very less....
but i think with the help of hybrid system like combination of gravity effect, ‘the rule of shoulder of Archimedes’, solar system and combination of capacitor bank we can constantly generate free electricity for one home???

Comment: It's already used with `tidal power`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_power

Answer (score 1):

No, the physics doesn't work that way.

Both gravity and magnetism are examples of [conservative vector fields](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field), which means (among other things) that the net change in energy for any closed path in the field is zero.

This means that you can't extract power from them via any continuous (repetitive) process. You can only use them to assist with the conversion of power from one form to another, such as with a motor or generator.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we use Gravitation Force for Generation of Free electricity?

Yes. See hydro-electricity. This initially uses solar power to evaporate water which later falls as rain. If the water is collected at a height suitably high enough to drive a turbine we use gravity to drive the turbine.

> How we can generate free electricity constantly?

Free in what way? Solar and hydro are free in that we don't pay for the fuel. We do pay for the hardware.

> ... with the help of magnetic field we can generate free electricity but its amount is very less, ...

This is a poorly worded sentence and makes no sense.

> ... also with the help of eccentric load we can generate free electricity but its speed is very less....

So is this.

> ... but i think with the help of hybrid system like combination of gravity effect, ‘the rule of shoulder of Archimedes’, solar system and combination of capacitor bank we can constantly generate free electricity for one home???

And this.